# Regex: Change to lowercase all the words that have uppercase letters from title html tag (except the first letter)

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to use regex to change to lowercase words that have uppercase letters

`<title>THE CHILDREN are at home.</title>`

**TO BECOME**

`<title>The children are at home.</title>`

So, I made a Python script that does the job:

```
page_title = 'THE CHILDREN are at home.'
title_words = page_title.split(' ')

new_title_words = list()
for w in title_words:
    if w.isupper():
        new_title_words.append(w.lower().capitalize())
    else:
        new_title_words.append(w)

page_title = " ".join(new_title_words)
print(page_title)
```

**But I want to use a regex formula for notepad++, instead of Python. Can anyone help me?**

Comment: Just select the text and then <ctrl><alt><u>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<title>.|\G)\h*\K[A-Z]+`
- Replace with: `\L$0`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
    <title>     # literally
    .           # any character
  |           # OR
    \G          # restart from last match position
)           # end group
\h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
[A-Z]+      # 1 or more capital letters
```

**Replacement:**

```
\L          # lowercased
$0          # the whole match
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: almost good, @Toto. But see this other case: `<title>THE CHILDREN are at HOME.</title>` or suppose I have all words with capital letters, and I want only the first letter from the first word with capital letter.

Comment: @JustMe: It already keeps the first letter of the first word in capital letter, look at the result: `The children...`

Comment: thanks a lot @Toto